# Getting usable data from proprietary-what-looks-like C# data file?

Tags: c#, .net, reverse-engineering, scientific-computing

I have output from a SRSLabs EC301 in .sec format, which is a proprietary binary format. There is some windows based software available for reading this file, but someone moved the tower which has the software I need, and while I am still trying to find it, I'm also parallelizing my search for getting useful data out of this file.

I've viewed the file with hexdump and get this:

```
 00000000  00 01 00 00 00 ff ff ff  ff 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
 00000010  00 06 01 00 00 00 0f 53  52 53 4c 61 62 20 31 2e  |.......SRSLab 1.|
 00000020  37 2e 30 2e 31 30 0b 00  01 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff  |7.0.10..........|
 00000030  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  04 01 00 00 00 0c 53 79  |..............Sy|
 00000040  73 74 65 6d 2e 49 6e 74  33 32 01 00 00 00 07 6d  |stem.Int32.....m|
 00000050  5f 76 61 6c 75 65 00 08  02 00 00 00 0b 00 01 00  |_value..........|
 00000060  00 00 ff ff ff ff 01 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 0c 02  |................|
 00000070  00 00 00 3e 53 52 53 4c  61 62 2c 20 56 65 72 73  |...>SRSLab, Vers|
 00000080  69 6f 6e 3d 31 2e 37 2e  30 2e 31 30 2c 20 43 75  |ion=1.7.0.10, Cu|
 00000090  6c 74 75 72 65 3d 6e 65  75 74 72 61 6c 2c 20 50  |lture=neutral, P|
 000000a0  75 62 6c 69 63 4b 65 79  54 6f 6b 65 6e 3d 6e 75  |ublicKeyToken=nu|
 000000b0  6c 6c 05 01 00 00 00 12  45 43 48 6f 73 74 41 70  |ll......ECHostAp|
 000000c0  70 2e 53 52 53 45 43 44  6f 63 02 00 00 00 09 65  |p.SRSECDoc.....e|
 000000d0  63 50 72 6f 6a 65 63 74  0b 6c 69 6e 65 4d 61 6e  |cProject.lineMan|
 000000e0  61 67 65 72 04 04 11 45  43 48 6f 73 74 41 70 70  |ager...ECHostApp|
 000000f0  2e 45 43 50 72 6a 63 74  02 00 00 00 15 45 43 48  |.ECPrjct.....ECH|
 00000100  6f 73 74 41 70 70 2e 4c  69 6e 65 4d 61 6e 61 67  |ostApp.LineManag|
 00000110  65 72 02 00 00 00 02 00  00 00 09 03 00 00 00 09  |er..............|
 00000120  04 00 00 00 0c 05 00 00  00 48 53 52 53 49 6e 73  |.........HSRSIns|
 00000130  74 72 75 6d 65 6e 74 50  6f 6f 6c 2c 20 56 65 72  |trumentPool, Ver|
 00000140  73 69 6f 6e 3d 31 2e 30  2e 30 2e 30 2c 20 43 75  |sion=1.0.0.0, Cu|
 00000150  6c 74 75 72 65 3d 6e 65  75 74 72 61 6c 2c 20 50  |lture=neutral, P|
 00000160  75 62 6c 69 63 4b 65 79  54 6f 6b 65 6e 3d 6e 75  |ublicKeyToken=nu|
 00000170  6c 6c 05 03 00 00 00 11  45 43 48 6f 73 74 41 70  |ll......ECHostAp|
 00000180  70 2e 45 43 50 72 6a 63  74 0b 00 00 00 0b 61 63  |p.ECPrjct.....ac|
 00000190  74 69 6f 6e 74 69 74 6c  65 0e 6f 62 73 65 72 76  |tiontitle.observ|
 000001a0  61 62 6c 65 4c 69 73 74  09 75 73 65 72 55 6e 69  |ableList.userUni|
 000001b0  74 73 06 72 65 70 65 61  74 08 6e 6f 64 65 52 6f  |ts.repeat.nodeRo|
 000001c0  6f 74 05 74 69 74 6c 65  06 72 65 6d 61 72 6b 0c  |ot.title.remark.|
 000001d0  6f 70 65 72 61 74 6f 72  4e 61 6d 65 04 64 61 74  |operatorName.dat|
 000001e0  65 0e 69 6e 73 74 72 75  6d 65 6e 74 4c 69 73 74  |e.instrumentList|
 000001f0  0a 6d 61 69 6e 72 65 70  65 61 74 01 02 04 00 04  |.mainrepeat.....|
 00000200  01 02 02 00 03 00 22 53  52 53 49 6e 73 74 72 75  |......"SRSInstru|
 00000210  6d 65 6e 74 50 6f 6f 6c  2e 55 73 65 72 44 65 66  |mentPool.UserDef|
 00000220  69 6e 65 64 55 6e 69 74  73 05 00 00 00 08 13 45  |inedUnits......E|
```

And so on. The output viewed as ASCII looks eerily like Java, so my question is: is this possibly some standard .NET pickle-like output that can be fairly easily loaded into a Java program to be read?

There are classes that aren't part of the .NET standard library, but I also decompressed the MSI installer and see some names I recognize, and believe them to be bytecode files.

Comment: `System.Int32`? Smells like .NET.

Comment: How do you know it's not C#?

Comment: Good point. I don't know, and you're absolutely right. System.Int32 is .NET. Will edit.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But the thing you are asking for assistance is not to solve a programming, an algorithm or a pattern issue with some code. To help you improve your requests, please read the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* and **Questions I avoid asking** at the top right.

Comment: This is definitely .net related, but it isn't code per se. It may be the result of serializing some data with e.g. `BinaryFormatter`.

Comment: Indeed- that's what I'm trying to determine.

Comment: I would suggest posting to https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/. They seem to have tags that point to binary analysis.